How to install 2024-04 LTS Desktop?
I am using a brand new Legion laptop with AMD 7945HX and 4080 with 32GB RAM.
All the other apps are running fine: Google Chrome, Steam, 3DMark, PalWorld, WuKong Benchmark.
I have installed Ubuntu on VirtualBox for more than a hundred times in the past.
Then I downloaded VirtualBox 7.0 and Ubuntu 2024-04 LTS.
But then the installation of Ubuntu may take 30 minutes and it is still not going forward.
I tried again and the "laser beam" kind of light that shows it is "moving along" is not moving at all, for 5 minutes.
I first set it to 8GB RAM allocated and 8 processors, and then I tried with 4 processors and 4GB, and then everything default. And it never worked.
Any real computer scientist or engineer can tell how to make it work?

There are numerous tutorials that relate, have you explored any?  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-run-ubuntu-desktop-on-a-virtual-machine-using-virtualbox https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-server etc...   Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is available in various products/forms, using different installers, and you've only specified a release.

FYI:  If an install appears locked, I leave the installer alone & switch to text terminal & explore what is going on... in QA due to my slow internet speeds and the large download/install options available some can take >60 mins on occasion, but you gave no specifics (95% of time taken up by download options... I prefer to install quickly & add additional later myself, but QA testcase requires what I test)

I have install Ubuntu on VirtualBox for more than a hundred times in the past.

Ubuntu Core? Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop? a Ubuntu flavor?   You've only mentioned Ubuntu and the release, but not which product.  There are three installers available for 24.04 LTS alone.. You select which you'll use at download time, thru product/ISO selection.  If you're familiar with Ubuntu (or any POSIX or OS) switch to terminal and explore.. even if installer is running confined (not all installers do) you can still pretty easily tell what system is doing by usual exploration of the OS at terminal.

to make the installation smooth, I let the "Download newer stuff and install them" unchecked

Desktop. I added in the subject line

so is the "laser beam" of light not moving at all for 15 minutes normal?

It'll depend on details I won't know, including your hardware (resources available), type of install, and if downloads are utilized speed of internet... I have QA test installs that take <120 seconds too... there is HUGE variation is how long due to type of install  (a non-destructive install which requires download of your existing manually installed packages will of course take much longer than a destructive install which ignores what was there beforehand)

Check your Virtualbox logs on the host OS.
